# Reload a label view text from sub class view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, class, label

I have one view controller class First.h/First.m where i have a method named `-(void)ChangeLabelName:(NSString *)title defined` in .h file.

```
(in First.m)
-(void)ChangeLabelName:(NSString *)title
{
    NSLog(@"in set label");
    [topheading_label setText:title];
}
```

Now i have second view controller class named Second.h/Second.m. I added this view controller as a subview to first view controller like-

```
(in First.m)
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
Second *second = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
[self.view addSubview:second.view];
```

In second.m i have a method named `- (void)call_summary:(id)sender`
    (Now in Second.m)

```
- (void)call_summary:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"in call summary click");
    First *first=[[First alloc] init];
    [first ChangeLabelName:@"My name is shivam"];
}
```

It is going in the method `-(void)ChangeLabelName:(NSString *)title.`But label text is not changing.
I used`[topheading_label setNeedsDisplay];.`But dint work for me.
Help me.`

Comment: No one is here to help me.. !! :(

Comment: hey buddy m here.. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use NotificationCenter. Register notification in First.m and post notification from Second.m.

Answer (score 1):

The reason your label is not updated is because you the second

```
- (void)call_summary:(id)sender
```

did not refer to the correct controller instance.

```
First *first=[[First alloc] init];
```

created a new First instance.

If you want to let Second talk to First, you could use delegate.

In Second.h, define a protocal like

```
@protocol SecondDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)ChangeLabelName:(NSString *)title;
@end
```

Add a new property:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <SecondDelegate> delegate;
```

In  First.h,

```
@interface First : UIViewController <SecondDelegate>
```

In First.m

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle: nil];
Second *second = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"second"];
second.delegate = self;
[self.view addSubview:second.view];
```

In Second.m callSummary:

```
- (void)call_summary:(id)sender
{
  NSLog(@"in call summary click");    
  [self.delegate ChangeLabelName:@"My name is shivam"];
}
```

For more information on Protocal, refer to [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

BTW, I would suggest you using lower case letter as prefix in Instance method, like: changeLabelName.

Comment: Still label text is not changing.. :(

Comment: Do you have a sample project? Perhaps something else is missing.

Answer (score 0):

**Method 1**

I suggest you to declare your `First` view controller in `appDelegate` and `synthesize`.

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) First *first;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
first=[[First alloc] init];
```

Now in your Second.m

```
- (void)call_summary:(id)sender
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate=(AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [appDelegate.first ChangeLabelName:@"My name is Rajneesh :D "];
}
```

**Method 2**

```
- (void)call_summary:(id)sender
{
    NSUserDefaults *def =[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [def setObject:@"My name is Rajneesh :D " forKey:@"lablString"];
}
```

in `Second's` `viewWillAppear`, set your text.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    yourLabel.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"lablString"];
}
```

**Method3**

Using `protocol`, look Kenny's answer

Comment: while the view is in running condition. How can u change its object value from sub view??

Comment: which one (method) you are implementing?

Comment: where you are allocation your First , 1st time?

Comment: in applicationdidfinishlaunching method.

Comment: i have implemented kenny way also your first method

Comment: have you synthesize object of your First?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30109/discussion-between-rajneesh071-and-shivam)

Comment: bhai chk to kar saare answer.. muje pahchana ya nai tune ?